# The inverse of stochastic matrices, how to classify them?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, soft-question, inverse, stochastic-matrices

Stochastic matrices $\bf P$ with element $p_{i,j}$ at row $i$ and column $j$ have some specific limitations to them, namely:

$$\cases{\displaystyle\sum_{\forall j} p_{i,j} = 1\\ p_{i_j} \geq 0}$$

Is there some way we can use these limitations to derive what restrictions will on their inverse ${\bf P}^{-1}$.

The properties I know of so far are limited to all $\lambda({\bf P}) \in [0,1]$ with one guaranteed eigenvalue always located at $1$ with corresponding eigenvector representing a ***steady-state***. But there can exist several of these. For example the matrix $${\bf P} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\1/3&1/3&1/3\\\end{bmatrix}$$
The both two first states are steady and the third is not.

Also as mentioned by @Stefan it is possible that $\lambda({\bf P}) =0$, making our matrix singular and impossible to invert. We will consider the matrices for which this does not happen.

---

My **own work** is limited to concluding that if any one vector has eigenvalue $1$, then there must exist a corresponding eigenvalue for the inverse which is the same, and this corresponding eigenvector for ${\bf P}^{-1}$ must correspond to the steady state eigenvector for $\bf P$.

But for the other eigenvectors of ${\bf P}^{-1}$, I don't know how to classify them. (or any other property which could be of interest)

Comment: Do you want to place additional assumptions on $\mathbf P$? Not all stochastic matrices are invertible, e.g. take the matrix with first row equal to $1$ and $0$ oterhwise. Also the eigenvalue $1$ might not be "unique" in the sense that there are multiple linear independent eigenvectors, take for example the identity matrix, which is also stochastic.

Comment: @Stefan Yep you are correct, I will update the question.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $P$ is an invertible, right-stochastic matrix. First, note the row sums of $P$ are equal to $1$, and as such so are the row sums of $P^{-1}$. (See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946776/show-that-sum-of-elements-of-rows-columns-of-a-matrix-is-equal-to-reciprocal-o).) Second, note that $P^{-1}$ is likewise right-stochastic if and only if $P$ is a permutation matrix (in which case $P = P^{-1}$). (See [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392978/when-are-the-inverses-of-stochastic-matrices-also-stochastic-matrices)). An implication of these two results is that each row in $P^{-1}$ contains at least one nonpositive element. That is to say that each row of $P^{-1}$ is necessarily an affine combination of the standard basis vectors, just not one that is a strict convex combination.

Let $\mathrm{conv}(M)$ denote the convex hull of the rows of matrix $M$. Geometrically, $\mathrm{conv}(P)$ is *enclosed by* the standard simplex (whose vertices are the standard basis vectors), and its inverse $P^{-1}$ is an *enclosure of* the standard simplex.

For example, if
$$
P = \left[ \begin{array}{3}
\color{blue}{0.60} & \color{blue}{0.30} & \color{blue}{0.10} \\
\color{orange}{0.15} & \color{orange}{0.70} & \color{orange}{0.15} \\
\color{green}{0.25} & \color{green}{0.00} & \color{green}{0.75}
\end{array} \right],
$$
then the geometry is as in the illustration below.

[image: geometry]

A notable special case is $P^{-1}$ with all off-diagonal elements nonpositive (and thus diagonal elements greater than or equal to $1$). In such a case, $P^{-1}$ is an [$M$-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix). Note that every invertible $M$-matrix with row sums equal to $1$ has a right-stochastic inverse.