# reverse of Transition Probability Density function

Tags: probability

Given 2 distributions with the probability density functions $p(x)$ and $q(y)$, and their transition probability density function $T(y,x)$, we have

$$q(y) = \int p(x)T(y,x) \mathrm dx$$

In which situation, there would exist a "reverse of transition probability density function" $R(y,x)$ such that

$$p(x) = \int q(y)R(y,x) \mathrm dy$$

and how to compute it?

I suppose in general $R(y,x)$ might not exist. For example, if $\forall x$, it maps to a particular $y^*$.

But in some situation, $R(y,x)$ exists and can be computed. For example, for a diffusion process $\mathrm dX = \mu \mathrm dX + \sigma \mathrm dW$, the (forward) transition probability density function $T(y,x)$ can be derived from Kolmogorov forward equation (ie Fokker–Planck equation); while the backward transition probability density function $R(y,x)$ can be derived from Kolmogorov backward equation.

So, in general, when would such $R(y,x)$ exist and be computable? if so, how to compute it?

Comment: I am confused. Given q, p there is always an operator such that q=Tp. The same applies to find R so that p=Rq. Would such a reasoning answer your question or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Thomas easiest is to consider the discrete scenario : e.g. $P =
\begin{pmatrix}\frac12 \\ \frac12 \end{pmatrix}$
and $T=
\begin{pmatrix}\frac12 & \frac14\\ \frac12 & \frac34\end{pmatrix}$.

Then
$Q = T\cdot P = 
\begin{pmatrix}\frac38 \\ \frac58 \end{pmatrix}$
Obviously $R=T^{-1}$ so that $P = R\cdot Q = T^{-1}\cdot Q$.
When $T$ is not inversible, $R$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations, done in the discrete setting:

- Given a probability vector $p$ and another probability vector $q$ there is always a stochastic matrix $T$ such that $Tp=q$ (I am considering the matrices acting on column vectors on the right rather than on row vectors from the left).

For the moment I have just a visual justification. For example let $n=3$. We can consider a stochastic matrix as a transition probability $T_{ji}=P(X_{n+1}=j|X_{n}=i)$ of a Markov chain, where $i,j=1..3$ are the states. We can than plot next to the other the probability distributions $p,q$ in the following visual way:

[image]

, where the total length of the big rectangles is $1$ and the length of the subrectangles are proportional to $p_i$ or $q_i$.

Using such plot we can build a Markov chain that evolves $p$ to $q$. For this purpose to evolve state $i$ we can check the projection of the rectangle associated with $p_i$ onto $q$. For example state 2 will be evolved into state 1 or 2 with a ratio of probabilities proportional to the length of the indicated arrows.

This justifies the fact that we can find stochastic $T$, $R$ such that $Tp=q$ and $Rq=p$ (actually we can find infinite many...). Of course $T,R$ need not be the inverse of the other here we are considering $p,q$ fixed.

- Stochastic matrices may not be invertible, e.g.:

$$\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
is not invertible. If the determinant is not zero, than it is invertible, but the inverse may not be a stochastic matrix (columns sum to 1 but the values may become negative, see for example here [Inverse of a regular stochastic matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779626/inverse-of-a-regular-stochastic-matrix) ).

Related:

https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.4169/college.math.j.44.2.108?journalCode=ucmj20

This should also very much be connected to time reversibility and convergence to equilibrium, but I guess it would take much longer to discuss this...

Comment: discrete time case is more straightforward that so long as $T$ is invertible, we got $R=T^{-1}$, but I can't see a criterion for the continuous case...

Comment: As a side point, from your question it was not clear if you are asking for q,p fixed or generic, as you can see from my answer. Further, also the discrete case has issues since you may lose stochasticity, even if the matrix is invertible....

Comment: I would leave comments in the continuous case to people more used than me with functional operators and kernels :)

Comment: To be a transition probability matrix, $T$ shall follow the the "sum as 1" constraint. While $R$ is a reverse work, not a transition probability, so "sum as 1$ is not required.

Comment: I guess it depends a bit on the question that you have.... maybe I investigated one that you are not interested in ;) that is why my message starts with 'some observations'

Comment: If you just want to invert an operator w.o. much constraints probably one should look at the concept of spectrum of an operator and look for material on line....

Comment: indeed, "reverse transition probability density function" is inaccurate, shall be "reverse of transition probability density function", thanks to point out so!